# Laravel site not showing content in sub-folder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I created a new version of my existing website and put it into its own folder in `/var/www/new_site`

`/var/www` is where the existing site is. `/var/www/stage` is where the new site is being developed.  I duplicated the stage folder and renamed it to `new_site`.

But I'm having trouble getting the server to recognize the folder.

Is it even possible to create a site whose files are in a sub-folder?

This is what my conf looks like which is enabled.

```
ServerName site.com
ServerAlias site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/new_site/public

<Directory /var/www/new_site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo Options
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The site uses the latest version of Laravel, Apache 2, and Ubuntu 18.

The last thing my developer told me was that we need to reroute the apache to use the site folder, then move the public files to public site folder.

Comment: It can be done in a subfolder... I have for testing purposes two different sites on same Ubuntu server like /var/www/site1 and /var/www/site1. I believe you have to give some permissions to the site folders otherwise server cannot read/write site folders.

Comment: @nikistag nice! question is how do I get my site to recognize the sub-folder?

Comment: Go to Step 4 of this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

Comment: you need to create a virtualhost for that specific folder

Comment: Sorry.. That was too much. You only have one site.

Comment: @Thamer what do you mean?

Comment: @user1114968 follow the tutorial that nikistag gave you and start from step 4, your actual config not enough

Comment: @Thamer I did follow it.  not sure what I am missing.  I setup the virtual host in the conf file.

Comment: check the owner of that folder it should be the running user $USER, and don't forget to reload your server

Comment: Before step 4 are commands to give server access to site folders.... End step 4 is to setup the site based on laravel. You need to replace laravel/localhost with your site... Careful there... The. Env file might have been edited by your developer https://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/

Comment: ok none of that is helping.  is there any specific that I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have access to ubuntu server?Can you Login to it?

Comment: yes. I am on a dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

First, server needs access to site folders:
Console commands to give access:

```
chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/new_site
chmod -R 755 /var/www/new_site
chmod -R 777 /var/www/new_site/storage
```

Then cd to /var/www/new_site/
To check things working type command

```
php artisan
```

if it shows a list of commands things are ok till now.

Now open for edit site configuration with nano or vim:

```
nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

This configuration should be for your old site. If that's the case change for your new site.

It should be something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/new_site/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/new_site>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

After saving configuration  you need to restart server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now cd to /var/www/new_site/ and open .env file.

```
sudo nano .env
```

Check if everything is ok there. It should look like this:

```
APP_NAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
DB_USERNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXX

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: I did all of those commands.  Nothing changed.  Site is still showing the old files from the /var/www folder

Comment: after changing my conf .. did you restart server?

Comment: yes, I restarted the server.  not sure what I am I supposed to change in the conf file.

Comment: see if your new site apears here ..   nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Comment: See the code in my original post.  That's the code I have in my conf file.  It's a duplicate of my 000-default conf file, which I deactivated.  I just replaced the old folder with my new folder.

Comment: My .env looks exactly like the .env file on my stage site (which is working) except for the app URL which is pointing to the main site.

Comment: LOL.. all that work and the problem is still there: my.conf or virtualHost configuration. I give up :).. my.conf looks OK. On my projects I use virtual hosts and sites-enabled configurations but it's irrelevant. This is the limit of my knowledge :).

Comment: Read my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it (at least it looks like it is fixed).

I ran the command "apache2ctl -S" (without the quotes) to confirm which Virtualhost the main site was really using.  Turns out the main site was using a .conf file that was in the sites-enabled folder but was not showing up in the sites-available folder so I totally missed it.  Made the proper edits to that file and to the .env file (apparently the database name was wrong) and the site is now pointing to the new files.